# Azure BlobClient how to iterate over all blobs in a container in chronological order (of write time)

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-blob-storage, blob

I am using the azure SDK Blob client and am trying to iterate over all blobs in a container in chronological order (via write time).

If a new blob is written I also want to continue to read the newest ones and stream in all the blobs in chronological order, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using the Azure SDK Blob client and am trying to iterate over all blobs in a container in chronological order (via write time).

You can use the code below to list all blobs in a container in chronological order of their last modified time using **`Azure.Storage.Blobs`** NuGet package in .NET.

**Code:**

```cs
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "xxxxxxx";
        string containerName = "test";

        await ListBlobsInChronologicalOrder(connectionString, containerName);
    }

    public static async Task ListBlobsInChronologicalOrder(string connectionString, string containerName)
    {
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        List<BlobItem> blobs = new List<BlobItem>();

        await foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None))
        {
            blobs.Add(blob);
        }

        blobs = blobs.OrderByDescending(b => b.Properties.LastModified).ToList();

        foreach (var blob in blobs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Blob name: {blob.Name}, Last modified: {blob.Properties.LastModified}");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code lists all blobs in a container in chronological order of their last modified time using Azure.Storage.Blobs. It initializes a BlobServiceClient and **`BlobContainerClient`**, and uses GetBlobsAsync to list the blobs. It then sorts and prints the blobs using the await **`foreach`** statement.

**Output:**

```
Blob name: sample_files.mp4, Last modified: 29-02-2024 05:28:51 +00:00
Blob name: demo1.pdf, Last modified: 10-01-2024 13:04:01 +00:00
Blob name: demo1.mp4, Last modified: 10-01-2024 13:03:19 +00:00
Blob name: 1GB.bin, Last modified: 10-01-2024 12:22:41 +00:00
Blob name: demo.mp4, Last modified: 10-01-2024 11:59:56 +00:00
Blob name: demo1.docx, Last modified: 27-12-2023 10:35:11 +00:00
Blob name: sample7.mp4, Last modified: 11-12-2023 06:40:21 +00:00
Blob name: sample.pdf, Last modified: 05-12-2023 11:11:47 +00:00
Blob name: example.pdf, Last modified: 05-12-2023 11:11:46 +00:00
```

[image: Blobs listed in chronological order]

**Reference:**

[List blobs with .NET - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list)